# Call an API on AWS API Gateway using Cognito Credentials from Android

Tags: android, api, amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito, aws-api-gateway

I am trying to use `AWS` `API` Gateway generated `android SDK` to call an `API` using `amazon Cognito` for authentication made using `AWS` `API` Gateway. Cant understand how to call the api's. Any pointers on how to make an API call from android using the generated API Gateway `Android SDK`. Have went through a lot of articles.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It might seem a bit confusing to start with. But it is similar to a normal SDK we use. 
Let's say you have a user post in your API, and you want to create a user with few parameters like name, email, phone number according to the json your API's accept, your code will look something like

You create an instance of your SDK with:

```
credentialsProvider = new CognitoCachingCredentialsProvider(
    context, 
    "identityPoolID",
    AMAZON_COGNITO_REGION
);

factory = new ApiClientFactory().credentialsProvider(credentialsProvider)
    .endpoint("<endpoint>");

INSTANCE.client = INSTANCE.factory.build(<class>.class);
```

You create an object of the User with:

```
UserModel output = new UserModel();
output.setFirstName("something");
output.setEmail("abc@xyc.com");
```

And then you make a user post with:

```
client.usersPost(output);
```

Hope it's clear.